# How could House Do'Urden be restored?

Tags: forgotten-realms, legend-of-drizzt

I've read from several sources the rulers of Menzoberranzan eventually restored House Do'Urden; except if I remember *The Dark Elf Trilogy*: *Exile* and *Legacy* correctly, all the members of the family were killed except for Drizzt, and he stayed on the surface world. How could a bloodline that's for all intents and purposes extinct be restored?

Comment: High-level magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Forgotten Realms wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/House_Do%27Urden), citing the 2014 R. A. Salvatore novel *[Night of the Hunter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18050140-night-of-the-hunter)* as its source, the house was reconstituted from unrelated noble drow.

> To form the house membership, Quenthel selected a number of drow from other houses, starting with her own sister, Sos'Umptu Baenre, to serve as temporary matron mother. Sos'Umptu was quickly replaced by Dahlia Sin'felle after her capture and corruption at the hands of Gromph Baenre and Methil El-Viddenvelp. Tiago Baenre was to serve as house weapon master after his return to Menzoberranzan. Tos'un Armgo, recently returned from the surface with his daughter, was to serve as house patron. The house's garrison and foot soldiers were taken from Bregan D'aerthe, supported by House Baenre. The house was given a position on the Ruling Council as the eighth house

Comment: So it's House Do'Urden in name only.